# Suppress warnings from boost includes

Tags: c++, boost, warnings

I have a c++ application (built under linux with g++ 4.8.3, boost 1.54) that spouts a lot of warnings about `boost`. Warnings include:

```
 /usr/local/include/boost/math/constants/constants.hpp:314:3: warning: non-standard suffix on floating constant [-Wpedantic]
BOOST_DEFINE_MATH_CONSTANT(rayleigh_skewness, 6.311106578189371381918993515442277798e-01, "6.31110657818937138191899351544227779844042203134719497658094585692926819617473725459905027032537306794400047264e-01")

/usr/local/include/boost/concept/detail/general.hpp:71:20: warning: typedef 'boost_concept_check228' locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
   BOOST_PP_CAT(boost_concept_check,__LINE__)

...
```

There are so many different ones . It looks like from here that you can suppress particular typedef warnings: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7242

But I would like to be able to suppress all of these warnings. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `-isystem` instead of `-I` to specify the include path for boost.

Comment: You can check [this library](https://github.com/ruslo/leathers#example-all). This approach works on Visual Studio and Xcode too (there is nothing like `-isystem` there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenter T.C. suggests, [warnings are suppressed for system headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html) in gcc. There are (at least) two ways of adding additional system include paths to your gcc build:

1. `-isystem` command line option, and
2. [`*_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html) (where '*' is `C`, `CPLUS`, or `OBJC`).

These mechanisms also work for clang.